# How to quick solve LP by LPSOLVE from JAVA

Tags: linear-programming, lpsolve

I have a LP problem witch is constructing from JAVA code. For my conveniences I create LP directly in **LP file format** in my code. To create LP file, I do not use a LP solve matrix equations, but directly write linear equations into a text variable, which then save to  LP file (this is more convenient for me of later checking the spelling).

But when using this method, I have to first write the LP to a file via FileWriter writer, and then comb it through lpSolve solver = lpSolve.readLp(.... and actually solve via solver.solve();
Or maybe there is a way to solve this system of equations **without writing and then reading from a file** (to make the process a little faster)?

Comment: I don't think LpSolve can read an LP file from a string. Of course, you could form the LP matrix A inside your Java code, but that may require a substantial rewrite.